# Episerver: Execute a Schedule Job within a schedule Job

Tags: episerver, optimizely

Is it possible to execute a schedule job within a schedule job .For Instance ,I have a schedule job A that does some operations .There is another schedule job B that executes after Schedule Job A is executed. So rather than manually going and running the job using admin mode which is a straightforward option, Is there a way wherein I can execute job B after Job A is executed successfully?
I found an interface IScheduledJobExecutor which looks like it does but i am not sure if this is advisible to do that.
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: "Start Manually" inside `EPiServer.UI.Admin.DatabaseJob.StartNow_Click` does exactly this `IScheduledJobExecutor.StartAsync` - so why not?

Answer (score 0):

I would not create dependencies between scheduled jobs like that. Instead, consider refactoring your code so that the business logic of *both* operations can be carried out in the same scheduled job.

So, let's say you refactor your code into `Foo()` and `Bar()`.

Then create the following for maximum flexibility:

1. `Scheduled Job A` which executes `Foo()` only
2. `Scheduled Job B` which executes `Bar()` only
3. `Scheduled Job C` which executes *both* `Foo()` and `Bar()`

Obviously, you might not need #1 and #2 unless there is good reason for executing the operations individually.

Comment: I do get your point but out of the two jobs that I have ,there is only 1 I can control. The other is a 3rd party schedule job. These two jobs needs to run sequentially one after another & so I am looking out for a way that makes sure that the two executes one after another.

Comment: Ah, I see, in that case I think `IScheduledJobExecutor` is the way to go.